# ¿Como puedo mostrar un mensaje de alert de error de login?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

he estado haciendo un CRUD, LogIn con MongoDB, Node Js, Bootstrap 5, Mongoose y MVC, pero en la parte del LogIn cuando un usuario intenta ingresar un correo o contraseña incorrecta quiero mostrar un mensaje de alert o algo parecido indicandole al usuario que ha ingresado datos incorrectos, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Me estoy basando con esta serie de videos [1/4 - CRUD con MongoDB, Node Js, Bootstrap 5, Mongoose y MVC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SOaTx6hxno&list=PLrAw40DbN0l3X-ol5MHc9UeyfdTcDCPcy)

Ya tengo el método en el que válida en mi base de datos, pero no sé cómo mostrar el error en Fronted, este es mi código

```
//validar correo y contrasenia
module.exports.validar = (req, res) => {

user.findOne({
        $and: [
            { correo: req.body.inputEmail },
            { contrasena: req.body.inputPassword },
        ],
    },

    (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
            return;
        }

        if (!result) {
            data = {
                meta: {
                    status: "Fallido",
                    message: "Inicio de Sesion, Fallido, Porfavor revise el Usuario o Contraseña",
                },
            };
            res.status(401).send(data);

        } else {
            data = {
                meta: {
                    status: "success",
                    message: "Login success",
                },
            };
            //res.json(data);
            res.redirect("/pqrs");
        }
    }
);
}
```

Me manda este mensaje cuando el inicio de sesión es fallido, pero yo quiero mostrar en el fronted un mensaje de error diciendo "Datos Incorrectos"

[image: Mensaje Error]

Y pues este es mi LogIn

[image: LogIn]

Comment: pues tienes todo en ese json que te llega en la respuesta, haces un if que valide si el ststus es fallido lanza un alert() con tu mensaje

Comment: Una recomendación: es una pésima idea almacenar el "password" del usuario en la base de datos, es preferible almacenar el hash, preferiblemente usando [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt)

Comment: osea en este if en vez de message lo cambio a alert?  if (!result) {
            data = {
                meta: {
                    status: "Fallido",
                    message: "Inicio de Sesion, Fallido, Porfavor revise el Usuario o Contraseña",
                },
            };
            res.status(401).send(data);